# Input type select return empty array in php validation

Tags: php, html, validation, drop-down-menu

I have using following function for clean form data.

```
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return htmlspecialchars($str);          
}
```

It gives empty array of the following field.

```
$value = clean($_POST['tags_id'];
```

and after removing clean() function, it give all selected value(means no empty array)

```
<select name="tags_id[]" multiple="multiple" data-rel="chosen" style="width: 220px">
<option value="1">value1</option>
<option value="2">value2</option>
<option value="3">value3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how you submit your form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  foreach($_POST['tags_id'] as $key => $val) {
    echo "val".clean($val); // Here you will get clean values
  }
}

function clean($str) {
  $str = @trim($str);

  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $str = stripslashes($str);
  }
  return htmlspecialchars($str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your form:

```
<select name="tags_id[]" multiple=...
                     ^^ here
```

You will see that `tags_id` is an array, so `$_POST['tags_id']` is an array.

You cannot use string functions on your array, you would have to loop over the elements of the array and call your `clean()` function on those. See here what happens when you use `trim()` on an array: [example](http://ideone.com/ZG6pCi).

You can also check in your function if the value is an array and handle it accordingly.